Sections of the structure sheaf
I'm having trouble understanding the definition of a structure sheaf. I'm not confident in my commutative algebra and in my category theory so please tell me if I'm missing some important insight. The definition I've been given of the structure sheaf of $X=\text{Spec}(A)$ is $$\mathcal{O}_X(U):=\{s\colon U\to\coprod A_p : \forall p\in U,s(p)\in A_p \text{ and } \forall p \in U\,\exists V_p\subset U,a,b\in A \text{ s.t. } \forall q\in V_p,q\neq b \;s(q)=\frac{a}{b}\in A_q\} $$
Now, the thing that confuses me is the last part. From my understanding, it basically means that locally around $p$ the section must be of the form $\frac{a}{b}$. I have trouble in thinking of an example of such function that isn't constant. I understand how this definition doesn't necessarily imply that every $s$ is constant but I am really struggling in actually "visualize" how such function would behave.Do you have any suggetion?

Notice that there are several other descriptions of the structure sheaf, which may be more intuitive depending on the reader. You will find them in the related questions here, so I will not repeat them.

Part of the reason you may be struggling to think of a function which isn't constant (here I assume constant means "just equal to $a$ for some $a\in A$") is that in fact $\mathcal{O}_X(X)=A$. So you'll have to look on a smaller open set to get interesting examples.
One standard example occurs when $A=k[x,y,z,w]/(xw-yz)$ and $U=X\setminus V(y,w)$. The function which is $x/y$ on $D(y)$ and $z/w$ on $D(w)$ is a perfectly good element of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ since on $D(y)\cap D(w)$ we have $x/y=z/w$, but there do not exist $a,b\in A$ so $a/b=x/y$ on $D(y)$ and $a/b=z/w$ on $D(w)$ and $b$ is nonvanishing on $U=D(y)\cup D(w)$. (ref, for instance)
